# How do you make an <img> move from <td> to <td> using arrow keys?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a 10x10 table, with an image in one of its cells . Here is the code.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
            var allTds = $("td")
            for(i in allTds){
                if(Math.random() < 0.4){
                    allTds.eq(i).addClass("block")
                }
            }
            var allOpen = $("td:not(.block)")
            var selectLoc1 = Math.floor(Math.random()*allOpen.length)
            var selectLoc2 = Math.floor(Math.random()*allOpen.length)
            var image = $("<img>")
            image.attr("src", "pawn.png")
            allOpen.eq(selectLoc1).append(image)
            allOpen.eq(selectLoc2).addClass("goal")
})
```

When user presses an arrow key, the image has to move from td to td depending on which arrow key is pressed. How can I implement this in the code that I will put? Thanks.

Comment: What research have you done and what have you tried? Stackoverflow isn't a free code writing service or a *"how to"* tutorial service. The objective here is for others to help you fix **your code** when it doesn't work as expected...not to write new features for you

Comment: TL;DR: add an evenlistener to keyup and check which arrow key was pressed (keycode are 37-40 for arrow key as I know).

Comment: @charlietfl I'm really worried how unfriendly this site can appear for someone new

Comment: And why is that? It is incumbent on you to research the basics. Take some time to read through the [help]. Also read [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)

Answer (score 2):

You have to detect the key down events and move the image to corresponding cell based on the key pressed.

For example suppose `imageCellRow, imageCellColumn` is the current location of the image. Then following logic would be used to move the image to new location.

```
switch(arrowKey) {
    case leftArrow:
        console.log("left");
        imageCellColumn--;
        break;
    case rightArrow:
        console.log("right");
        imageCellColumn++;
        break;
    case upArrow:
        console.log("up");
        imageCellRow--;
        break;
    case downArrow:
        console.log("down");
        imageCellRow++;
        break;
}

imageCellRow = (imageCellRow + height) % height;
imageCellColumn = (imageCellColumn + width) % width;
```

Now you have the new location of the image, all that's left is to remove the old image and add it to the new location.

Here's working example (Click on the generated table and then press arrow keys)

```js
$(function () {
 //console.log("started");
 var tableWidth = 5;
 var tableHeight = 5;
 var imageUrl = "https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2013/07/12/15/02/penguin-149275_960_720.png";
 var image = $("<img src='" + imageUrl + "'>");
 
 generateTable(tableWidth, tableHeight);
 addImageToCell($("table"), image, 0, 0);
 
 /* <Image movement logic> */
 (function () {
  var table = $("table");
  var width = table.find("tr:first td").length;
  var height = table.find("tr").length;
  //console.log("table dim: " + width + "," + height);

  //Initial image cell
  var imageCellRow = 0;
  var imageCellColumn = 0;
   
  var leftArrow = 37;
  var upArrow = 38;
  var rightArrow = 39;
  var downArrow = 40;
  
  $(document).keydown(function (e) {
   //Remove image from current Cell
   table.find("tr:eq(" + imageCellRow + ") td:eq(" + imageCellColumn +") img").remove();
   
   switch(e.which) {
    case leftArrow:
     //console.log("left");
     imageCellColumn--;
     break;
    case rightArrow:
     //console.log("right");
     imageCellColumn++;
     break;
    case upArrow:
     //console.log("up");
     imageCellRow--;
     break;
    case downArrow:
     //console.log("down");
     imageCellRow++;
     break;
   }
   imageCellRow = (imageCellRow + height) % height;
   imageCellColumn = (imageCellColumn + width) % width;
   
   addImageToCell(table, image, imageCellRow, imageCellColumn);
  });
 })();
 /* <Image movement logic /> */
 
 //Generates table with given dimensions
 function generateTable(width, height) {
  var table = "<table>";
  
  for(var j = 0; j < height; j++) {
   table += "<tr>";
   for(var i = 0; i < width; i++) {
    table += "<td/>";
   }
   table += "</tr>";
  }
  
  table += "</table>";
  
  $("body").append(table);
 }
 
 function addImageToCell(table, image, cellRow, cellColumn) {
  table.find("tr:eq(" + cellRow + ") td:eq(" + cellColumn +")").append(image);
 }
});
```

```html
<html>
<head>
 <script
   src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"
   integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4="
   crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
 <script src="app.js"></script>
 
 <style>
  td {
   width: 50px;
   height: 50px;
   border: 1px solid black;
  }
  td img {
   width: 45px;
   height: 45px;
  }
 </style>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I like how you made that jQuery really self-explaining!

Answer (score 1):

Thats an example only for background Change and walking through the table...
I think the rest is simple....

```html
  <!doctype html>
  <html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Table key´s</title>
    <style>
      td{width:20px;height:20px;background:#ddd;}
      tr:nth-child(5) td:nth-child(5){background:#f00;}
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="tableContainer">
    </div>
    <script>    
      var row=col=5,max=10;
      tableContainer.innerHTML = '<table>'+('<tr>'+'<td>'.repeat(max)).repeat(max)+'</table>';
      window.addEventListener("keyup", function(e){
        var colDiff, rowDiff;
        var keyMap = new Map([[37,[-1,0]],[38,[0,-1]],[39,[1,0]],[40,[0,1]]]);
        if (keyMap.has(e.keyCode)){
          document.querySelector(`tr:nth-child(${row}) td:nth-child(${col})`).style.background='#ddd';
          [colDiff,rowDiff]=keyMap.get(e.keyCode);
          row+=rowDiff;
          col+=colDiff;
          row = (row>max) ? max : (row < 1) ? 1 : row;
          col = (col>max) ? max : (col < 1) ? 1 : col;
          document.querySelector(`tr:nth-child(${row}) td:nth-child(${col})`).style.background='#f00';
        }
      }) 
    </script>
  </body>
  </html>
```

you can also use the table object...

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Table key´s</title>
  <style>
    td{width:20px;height:20px;background:#ddd;}
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="tableContainer">
  </div>
  <script>    
    var aktRow=aktCol=4,max=9;
    tableContainer.innerHTML = '<table id="mt">'+('<tr>'+'<td></td>'.repeat(max+1)+'</tr>').repeat(max+1)+'</table>';
    mt.rows[aktRow].cells[aktCol].style.background='#f00';
    window.addEventListener("keyup", function(e){
      var colDiff, rowDiff;
      var keyMap = new Map([[37,[-1,0]],[38,[0,-1]],[39,[1,0]],[40,[0,1]]]);
      if (keyMap.has(e.keyCode)){
        mt.rows[aktRow].cells[aktCol].style.background='#ddd';
        [colDiff,rowDiff]=keyMap.get(e.keyCode);
        aktRow+=rowDiff;
        aktCol+=colDiff;
        aktRow = (aktRow>max) ? max : (aktRow < 0) ? 0 : aktRow;
        aktCol = (aktCol>max) ? max : (aktCol < 0) ? 0 : aktCol;
        mt.rows[aktRow].cells[aktCol].style.background='#f00';
      }
    }) 
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I also vote for your answer. I don´t need jQuery ;-)